# Need a way to style elements that I can't access

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system

There is a page that I'm trying to style the border of a wrapper of. More so re-style it as there is an image based background that I need to change. However, the page exists in a template with which the body tag I am not able to access. The problem really exists in the fact that the wrapper is done with a table inside of a div (which has a class and and ID), but no way to really do any descendant CSS since the left vertical borders take one image (a 4px x 4px gif that repeats-y) and the top and bottom borders have the same gif that x-repeats, BUT the corners are all rounded-corner .gifs (to compensate for the lack of support in older IE browsers to render HTML5/CSS3) that differ at each corner.

Since all of the borders are done with classless, id-less td's (they just all fall under an ID and a class that will effect all of the borders if I use descendant CSS), and furthermore styled element-inline and in an area of the page that I do not have access to via the editor in the CMS, there is no way to make the changes.

I'm wondering if there is some JavaScript or jQuery that I can use to perhaps manipulate the CSS of these tables and change the borders.

Please advise, thanks for any help!

Comment: Look into [nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/), it may help.  Also might post the relevant code so that people can see what's going on.

Comment: would love to, but IE8 won't support nth-child, and (unfortunately, I HAVE to make sure it works in browsers down to IE8). Also I didn't post code because I don't feel that it is relevant, the situation explained should suffice. Thanks though because I completely forgot about nth-child :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find the tds that references this particular image in the style attribute in CSS or jQuery with a selector like:

```
td[style*="gif that repeats"] {
    border: replacement style !important;
}
```

If you need to support older browsers that lacks this kind of selector, you can still use it in jQuery:

```
$( 'td[style*="gif that repeats"]' ).css('border', 'new style');
```

The documentation for this selector is available at: **http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "targeted browser". This isn't a browser-specific issue, but I am trying to find a way to change the background image of specific table cells that make up the border of a content-wrapper. Am I missing something in your answer? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Yes I meant that if you plan to support browser likes Internet Explorer <= 6, the attributes selector will not work. So you can use jQuery 1.x as a workaround for IE6.